# "unlayout" a child view in View#onLayout when reusing views

Tags: android, layout, view

I have an Android View where I'm overriding `onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)`. This view is bound to items in a list view so the view tends to get reused. For certain items, I `childViewA.layout(l, t, r, b)` and for other items, I don't. That is, `child view A` is only visible in some items. However, when I use this logic, `child view A` simply retains its position from its layout in the previous item. It doesn't disappear as expected just because we're not calling `layout(l, t, r, b)` in the current view bind. It stays as-is from the earlier bind. Anyone know why it works this way? I would assume each view is laid out afresh in each layout call and not just repositioned from the earlier layout call. Is my only way out to call `setVisibility`?

Sample method:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  if (condition) {
    childViewA.layout(l1, t1, r1, b1);
  }
  childViewB.layout(l2, t2, r2, b2);
  childViewC.layout(l3, t3, r3, b3); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  if (condition) {
    childViewA.layout(l1, t1, r1, b1);
  }
  else{
    childViewA.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  childViewB.layout(l2, t2, r2, b2);
  childViewC.layout(l3, t3, r3, b3); 
}
```

The problem is that you aren't calling layout to childViewA at all when you DON'T want it to be there - so it keeps the old layout.